# Autofill Class Variable in Dart

Tags: flutter, class, dart

I'm working on a Flutter app that displays personal information about users. For this I am using Provider and I have two main classes, `Customer` and `Seller`. Each have a child class defined as `Person` like this:

Person:

```
class Person {
  String name;
  String lastName;
  late String fullName
  Persona({
   this.name = '',
   this.lastName = '',
  }){
   fullName = '$name $lastName'
  }
}
```

Customer:

```
class Customer extends ChangeNotifier{
  late Person personalData;
  int? requestedServices;
  Customer({
   this.requestedServices;
  }){
    personalData = Person();
  }

  updateFirstName(String value){
    this.fristName = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  updateLastName(String value){
    this.lastName = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }

}
```

Seller:

```
class Seller extends ChangeNotifier{
  late Person personalData;
  int? givenServices;
  Seller({
   this.givenServices;
  }){
    personalData = Person();
  }

  updateFirstName(String value){
    this.fristName = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  updateLastName(String value){
    this.lastName = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }

}
```

Then, I have a couple buttons and three text fields to update the info in the widget like this:

```
...

Customer customer= Provider.of<Customer >(context, listen: false);

...

ElevatedButton(
 ...
 onPressed:(){
   _customer.updateFirstName(_firstName);
   setState((){});
 }
)

ElevatedButton(
 ...
 onPressed:(){
   _customer.updateLastName(_lastName);
   setState((){});
 }
)

Consumer<Customer>(
  builder(context, Customer customer, Widget? child){
    return Column(
      children[
        Text('${customer.personalData.firstName}'),
        Text('${customer.personalData.lastName}'),
        Text('${customer.personalData.fullName}'),
      ]
    ),
  },
);
```

The first name and last name update just fine but the full name remains blank.

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

When you call `updateFirstName(String value)` for example, you just update the field `firstName` but not `fullName`

To make it more simple, you can do this:

```
Consumer<Customer>(
  builder(context, Customer customer, Widget? child){
    return Column(
      children[
        Text('${customer.personalData.firstName}'),
        Text('${customer.personalData.lastName}'),
        Text('${customer.personalData.firstName} ${customer.personalData.lastName}'),
      ]
    ),
  },
);
```

Comment: Thaks a lot for the response! Do you know a way to ¨bind¨ the FullName to the first and last name so it gets automatically updated?